# ansible: why it looks for vultr.ini file?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I have created the following playbook to create a vultr machine. I'm using the vultr module of ansible and have put all the necessary parameters;

```
---

# Ansible Blocks
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
#  gather_facts: False
  connection: local
  tasks:

    - block:
      - name: List root
        local_action:
          module: vr_server
          name: "myserver"
          os: CentOS 7 x64
          plan: 1024 MB RAM,25 GB SSD,1.00 TB BW
          region: Amsterdam
          api_key: "242HXXXXXXC3HGGXPSZTK7ILY4QUEC5KN555"
          api_account: "john"

      rescue:
        - name: Only run when a task inside the block throws an error.
          debug: msg="Something went wrong."

      always:
        - name: Always run.
          debug: msg="Regardless of what happened above, we're done with this block!"

...
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Config file not found. Tried : /home/john/.vultr.ini, /home/john/automation/utils/ansible-vultr/core_vultr/vultr.ini"}
```

It looks like, it's searching for vultr.ini. Why is it like that? what should I put in the vultr.ini file?

The version of Ansible is 2.5.0 and it's running on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this link may be exactly what you're looking for: https://www.renemoser.net/blog/2018/03/18/begin-vultr-with-ansible/

Specifically, you may want this bit:

```
[default]
key = <your api key>
```